# Advantages and disadvantages of sharing the existing geospatial tools over the web as geoprocessing services

Tags: arcgis-online, geoprocessing-service

So I started learning ArcGIS for Server, in an exercise I needed to answer this question above, sadly I couldn't figure out as to what the advantages and disadvantages were. I have developed a geoprocessing tool that makes buffer around a point feature, then I uploaded that tool to ArcGIS online. Last step was to answer this question. So basically, this tool could already be found on ArcGIS Online, therefore I should be determining what the advantages and disadvantages were of me sharing it again.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of sharing existing Spatial Analyst tools over the web?

Comment: What existing services ? What are your requirements, or what are you trying to achieve.  You first need to know the what you are trying to do, before you can assess the pros and cons of any particular approach.

Comment: To reformulate the question: what are the advantages and disadvantages of sharing exiting spatial analyst tools over the web?

Comment: Please edit the question to add more details

Answer (score 1):

Advantage - Webtools that are shared allow users to have access to functionality without having the software installed on their machines.  Not all potential users will have ESRI Spatial Analyst Extension software or even ArcGIS desktop software but they can still take advantage of the tools you provide.

Disadvantage - Running tools with large Dataset inputs might not run very effectively over an internet connection but will run fine using the spatial analyst software.

Comment: Yes this could be it, but why sharing existing geoprocessing tools?